# Get bytes from stream with php

Tags: php, streaming, byte, audio-streaming, flv

I know that streaming flv with php is possible, there are libraries out there for that but my question is, is it possible to get bytes from flv stream and use them to draw sound wave shape and export is a jpg or png bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [FFMPEG to extract the audio](http://savvyadmin.com/extract-audio-from-video-files-to-wav-using-ffmpeg/) portion and convert to a temporary WAV file.
2. Run [one of the many scripts available](http://mydons.com/drawing-easy-wave-graph-for-wave-audio-file-with-php/) on this WAV to generate the wave print you want.

Answer (score 1):

When receiving the data in PHP, it'll most likely be stored as a string. PHP strings are simply byte sequences. So `$string[0]` gives you the first byte of the string. That's all you need to do to get a byte in PHP.

Comment: Can I use sabreAMF or phpAmf to do this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. Maybe you should open a more specific question about this.